# How to add a listener for locale change?

Tags: java, listener, locale, aop

I'm now looking for a way to monitor JVM's default locale, that is, whenever `Locale.setDefault` is called, a listener method is automatically executed.

Maybe some byte-code engineering or AOP libraries can work but I'm not familiar with them... Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With AspectJ it is quite simple:

**Sample driver class**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.GERMAN);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.FRENCH);
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
    }
}
```

**Intercepting aspect**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aop;

import java.util.Locale;

public aspect DefaultLocaleWatchdog {
    after() : call(* Locale.setDefault(*)) {
        System.out.println("Default locale has been changed to " + Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Default locale has been changed to de
Default locale has been changed to fr
Default locale has been changed to en
```

BTW, if the locale is changed by code which is not under your control and into which you cannot weave, you need to weave `execution` advice into the JDK/JRE classes which is possible (I have done it before), but non-trivial and beyond the scope of this answer. But if e.g. the calls come from libs under your control, you can still do binary or load-time weaving on the libs (even on 3rd-party ones), leaving your JDK untouched.

Generally, if you want to weave into `call` joinpoints you need to weave the caller, if you want to weave into `execution` joinpoints you need to weave the callee. Which options you have always depends on which code you can control.

Comment: I need to monitor all calls to `Locale.setDefault`, so I must weave into JRE classes, right? Could you show the code? Thanks a lot!

Comment: As I said, if you want to weave the callee rather than the caller, just exchange `call` for `execution`. Are you really sure this is necessary? It would be easier to weave the calling code, even if it is 3rd party libs which you can handle via LTW.

Comment: I think what I need is RTW, but it's not supported yet as of AspectJ 5 (see http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/devguide/ltw.html). Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer. If no better idea comes out, I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: I've found the solution, that is to use `java.lang.instrunment` with a BCEL framework. As I have promised, I'll still accept your answer, after all it can partly solve the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, a hacked version of BCEL is also used internally by AspectJ, even though there has been discussion to switch to ASM. Because I am curious: Did you instrument the JDK classes or the callers? And did you do it during runtime or did you create an instrumented JDK on disk?